# Saving DataTable to MS Access Table

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

Background information:

I have a DataGridView, I can load a table from MS Access into it and/or also add data. It is not databound (and I don't want t).
What I did previously was to delete the data from  MS Access table before saving new data. But I would like to do it the proper way (+ there will be less chance of losing data).

---

Issue:
When I do

```
Adapter.Update(DataTable) 'OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
```

the data simply gets added (inserted) at the end, like when you add rows to datagridview.

What I want to do is overwrite the data in MS Access table, so that it looks identically to newly saved data (rows that can be updated get updated, new ones added, removed ones deleted)

In other words, if I'm saving 6 rows, I want to see 6 rows in database, not more not less.

---

I also tried loading the data, then changing it, and saving it back, but the result is the same. Eg if I load 5 rows, and save 5 rows, I end up with 10 rows in it after that save.

```
Adapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " & DB_TableName, DB_Connection)
Dim TempDataTable As New DataTable
BotDB_Adapter.Fill(TempDataTable )
    'edit data here
Adapter.Update(TempDataTable)
```

---

TLDR : How do I save a DataTable to MS Access table so that it overwrites data already in it.

Comment: What you almost certainly should be doing is calling `Fill` on a data adapter to populate a `DataTable`, binding that `DataTable` to your `DataGridView`, editing the data, then calling `Update` on the same data adapter to save the changes from the `DataTable` back to the database.  If you're not doing that, why not?

Comment: I am Filling, but I don't want it bound as I wrote in the original question already.

Comment: The question is WHY do you not want it bound. There can be valid reasons but, in the vast majority of cases, when I have seen people say that they don't want to use data-binding, it has been for bad reasons. I'm not in the habit of helping people do the wrong thing. If I understand your motivation then I can ensure that the advice I give is actually helpful and not detrimental.

Comment: That said, what happens to a `DataRow` when you call `Update` on a data adapter depends on the `RowState` of that `DataRow`. If the `RowState` is `Unchanged` then the row is ignored. If the `RowState` is `Added`, `Modified` or `Deleted` then the row will be inserted, updated or deleted respectively. If you just add a row to a `DataTable` then it's `RowState` will be `Added` so that row is going to be inserted, whether you like it or not. Normally, you retrieve data by calling `Fill` and all rows are `Unchanged`, then you edit a row and it becomes `Modified`.

Comment: If you don't want to retrieve and edit data, you can add a row and then call its `SetModified` method to set the `RowState` to `Modified` explicitly. You'll just have to ensure that optimistic concurrency is not in use because you won't have the original data for that row so you won't be able to match what's currently in the database.

Comment: I've been looking at the details... Even though data is the same, row state was "added" due to the way I was editing the rows [deleting and adding new ones, with more or less same data] So it seems I will have compare the two tables (the saved one and the current one) then set proper states for rows in order to make the .update work the same way as if it was bound then edited. I currently do not see an alternative to that (other than what I have now, delete saved table > insert current table). Delete>Insert happen momentarily one after another, what is the chance of losing data?

Comment: One option to ensure no data loss when performing that multi-step save is to wrap it in a transaction.  That way, if you complete the deletion but the insertion fails, the transaction will be rolled back and the deletion reversed.

Comment: I don't see any way for it to fail other than the power loss in a very bad moment. I don't think this would help with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to row state being "added", the only way to fix it is altering individual row states to proper states.

I do not see other way to solve this so I'll close it as there aren't any better answers.